# JavaScript Password function outputs wrong data

Tags: javascript, html

Updated version: 
The new version looks like this, but still doesnt work, any fixes

```js
var pw = "1234";

function checkpw(event, input) {
  var x = document.getElementById("pw").value;
  
  if (x.value === "") {
    alert("no password entered");
  } else if (x.value !== pw) {
    alert("wrong password");
  } else {
    alert("correct pw");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="password" id="pw" oninput="">
  <button type="submit" onclick="checkpw(event, this)">submit</button>
</body>

</html>
```

The code above still only outputs wrong password.

Comment: You are setting `x` to the input element, not the value of that element. See: [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: Also the input has no id `pw`. Do note that you should not use passwords this way. It is not safe at all. Everyone can retrieve your password from the javascript source.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the `value` of the input field to get the appropriate text value to compare. Also, your logic should check for empty first then wrong.

```js
var pw = "1234";

function checkpw(event, input) {
  var x = document.getElementById("pw"); // could be `input` instead
  
  if (x.value === "") {
    console.log("no password entered");
  } else if (x.value !== pw) {
    console.log("wrong password");
  } else {
    console.log("correct pw");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="pw" oninput="checkpw(event, this)">
```

I recommend wrapping the field in a form form.

**Note:** Never perform authentication on the client.

```js
const loginForm = document.forms.login;
const expectedPassword = '1234';

const authenticate = (event, form) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const actualPassword = new FormData(form).get('password').trim();

  console.log(checkPassword(actualPassword));
};

const checkPassword = (actualPassword) => {
  if (actualPassword.length === 0) {
    return 'No password entered';
  } else if (actualPassword !== expectedPassword) {
    return 'Wrong password';
  } else {
    return 'Correct pw';
  }
};
```

```html
<form name="login" onsubmit="authenticate(event, this)" autocomplete="off">
  <label for="pw">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="pw" name="password" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkpw() {
  var x = document.getElementById("pw");
  var pw = "1234";
  if (x.value == pw) {
  //--------^ the variable x refers to the element itself. x.value is what you are looking for
      alert("correct pw");
  } else if(x.value == "") {
  //--------^ pw equals to "1234" which is the variable you created. replace pw with x.value instead (consider doing x.value.trim())
      alert("no password entered");
  } else {
      alert("wrong password");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="pw" />
<!---------------------^ I've added an id attribute since your code uses getElementById and that requires an id --->
<button onclick="checkpw()">Check password</button>
```

Comment: Everything worked except for the no password entered alert. I also tried the identical to  (===) boolean, but it still won't display. It's fine, but on most websites, it has that.

Comment: @BenjaminMueller I found the issue. it's the `else if` that was incorrect. I've updated the snippet. could you try now?